# React(Vite), Typescript and i18n

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, i18next

I'm trying to implement i18n in my project, but I get some weird errors with typescript.

This is my i18n.ts file:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import packageJson from "../../package.json";

i18next
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(HttpApi)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "it",
        debug: false,
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        backend: {
            loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?" + packageJson.version,
        },
        detection: {
            order: ["cookie", "localStorage", "htmlTag", "path", "subdomain"],
            caches: ["cookie"]
        },
        returnNull: false
    });
```

This is my i18next.d.ts file:

```
import translation from '../public/locales/en/translation.json';

declare module 'i18next' {
    interface CustomTypeOptions {
        defaultNS: 'translation';
        resources: {
            translation: typeof translation;
        };
    }
}
```

The translation are working fine but I get this weird errors in my IDE(webstorm) and I don't understand why:

Error on:

```
<div>
   {t('pages.login.login_button')}
</div>
```

> Argument type "pages.login.login_button" is not assignable to parameter type any

Error on the i18next.init callback:

> Argument type {defaultNS: string, detection: {caches: string[], order: string[]}, debug: boolean, returnNull: boolean, backend: {loadPath: string}, fallbackLng: string} is not assignable to parameter type Callback | undefined

I think the problem is maybe with the vite or ts config?